# Android XML layout messed up?

Tags: android, xml

[XML Link](http://pastebin.com/T0HgiRTA)

I am designing an app with multiple buttons, but it isn't working properly.

**This is how it shows in Android studio**
[image: How it shows in the Android studio]

**This is how it shows in the emulator**
[image]

Comment: Do you hide the ProgressBar with visibility=gone? Try using visibility=invisible

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason for this could be you have multiple layout files for various screen density / screen dimensions / android version.

Check your layout folder and ensure there is not multiple lauout files in multiple folders ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your XML definition:

```
    <Button
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />
```

You're basing the position of the "Sign-Up" button to the "Back" button by stating this:

```
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
```

I'm going to make an assumption that you're hiding `button5` by using `View.GONE` which, in turn, will practically prevent `button5` from being drawn.

Now with `button5` missing from your layout, `button2` will no longer have a base to rely on. Thus making it shift all the way to the left.

The solution is pretty simple: Use `View.INVISIBLE` and not `View.GONE` to hide views that are being depended with another:

- If you're hiding it via XML:

  ```
      android:visibility="invisible"
  ```
- If you're hiding it programatically via Java:

  ```
      button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `circular dependancy` in your xml layout.

You can't / shouldn't do:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5" />
```

Set the position of one of them based on parent only (e.g. `alignParentLeft="true"`), and then you can set the position of the other based on the first button.
`Circular dependancies` have unexpected results, that may display different results in `Studio` and in `Android`, or in different versions of `Android`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the display is correct in android studio, but taking a quick look at your xml, you can see that the reference for `back button` and `sign up button` is messed up. Remember, relative layout uses the concept of having a `view A` which you can use as a reference for position of `view B`, in your xml you have:

```
<Button
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />
```

`button5` references `button2` and vice versa, one of the problems here is you don't even know where `button2` is, yet you used it as a reference. Also, `button5` depends on the position of `button2` yet you used `button5` as a reference for `button2`.

I suggest using `editText2` as a reference for both of your buttons since `editText2` has established its position. Use `android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"`, then just add top margin depending on what you want. after that, use

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

for back button, use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

for signup button. Then you can just adjust the margin for both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependancy in your xml layout.

you can see

Try This

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="email"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:hint="pass"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

<Button
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```